# How can i combine these 2 AHK scripts? Any help please

Tags: script, autohotkey

can someone please help me? I am trying to merge these 2 scripts in 1, but i keep getting errors. I thought just combining them would work, but sadly it has not lol. The 2 scripts are below.

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input

~F6::Suspend
~End::ExitApp
~F5::Reload

LCtrl & ~LButton::
Loop
If GetKeyState("LButton", "LCtrl") {
    Sleep, 6
    moveAmount := (moveAmount = 2) ? 1 : 0
    mouseXY(moveAmount,7.5)

}
else
break

Return



mouseXY(x,y)
{
DllCall("mouse_event",int,1,int,x,int,y,uint,0,uint,0)
}
```

The second script is this one -

```
f2::Suspend
;Script

~$*LButton::
{
Loop
{
SetMouseDelay 69
MouseClick, Left
If (GetKeyState("LButton","P")=0)
{
Break
Return
}
}
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
~F6::Suspend
~F5::Reload
~End::ExitApp

LCtrl & ~LButton::
    SetTimer, pulldown, 6
    SetTimer, click, 69
Return

$LButton::
    SetTimer, click, 69
return

pulldown:
    If (GetKeyState("LButton", "P") && GetKeyState("LCtrl","P"))
    {
        mouseXY(0,7.5)
    } else {
        SetTimer, pulldown, Off
    }
return

click:
    SetMouseDelay 69
    MouseClick, Left
    If (!GetKeyState("LButton","P"))
    {
        SetTimer, click, off
    }
return

mouseXY(x,y)
{
    DllCall("mouse_event",int,1,int,x,int,y,uint,0,uint,0)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. The first part of the script works, meaning it pulls down my mouse for me, but the auto left click does not work.

Comment: My bad. I don't know what I was thinking. Try now.